# How can I add SQLite3.dll to my Project?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, visual-studio-2015, sqlite-net

I'm building an WPF C# Application with an embedded SQLite Database.

But when I debug it I always get an exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException'.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite;
using System.Collections;
namespace SheepMaster
    {
        class SheepDao : IEnumerable
        {

            private List<Sheep> sheeps { get; set; }

            private SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("sheeps.db");

            public SheepDao()
            {

                con.CreateTable<Sheep>();
                sheeps = con.Table<Sheep>().ToList();
            }

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                return sheeps.GetEnumerator();
            }

            public void add(Sheep value)
            {
                sheeps.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to install sqlite from nuget I am getting the following error message:

Could not install package 'sqlite.redist 3.8.4.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

and when I manually install it I get this message:

A reference to *path* could not be added...

System.Data.SQLite
I installed it trought nuget but it didn't change anything.

Comment: search nuget packages and add the dll to your project from that otherwise if you have the dll then just add reference

Comment: Also make sure you have a `using` statement that imports SQLiteConnection.

Comment: Have you tried Install-Package System.Data.SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Either download and install sqlite3.dll from: http://sqlite.org/download.html
or Find on nuget package SQLite v3.13.